# I want to combine/union two tables and have it create a field that identifies which table it came from

Tags: sql, ms-access

I want to combine/union two tables and have it create a field that identifies which table it came from. I saw an answer for SQL but I do not need max values. I just need to Union two tables. Here is my current SQL for a union query I made through access' query.

SELECT [TableA].[1As], [TableA].[2As]
UNION
SELECT [TableB].[1As], [TableA].[2As];

I want the tables to create whichtabl field and populate whatever word I tell it based on the the table it came from to look like this:

```
Fields:    1As       2As    WhichTabl

data:      100       1      TableA
           110       0      TableB
```

thanks in advanced! Please excuse me I am a newbie!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add in the column as a constant:

```
SELECT "TableA" as which, [TableA].[1As], [TableA].[2As]
FROM TableA
UNION ALL
SELECT "TableB", [TableB].[1As], [TableB].[2As]
FROM TableB
```