# How to combine two tables into one with a new field with table source?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

```
table one
+-----+--------+--------+
|date |index   |idOne   |
|-----+--------|--------+
|     |        |        |

table two
+-----+--------+--------+
|date | index  | idTwo  |
|-----+--------|--------+
|     |        |        |


query result where index = "5"

+---------+--------+--------+----------+
|date     | index  |   id   |  idType  |
|---------+--------|--------+----------+
|10/10/91 |   5    |   1    |   One    |
|10/11/91 |   5    |   2    |   One    |
|10/12/91 |   5    |   1    |   Two    |
```

These are related questions **but not the same**:

This one has no different fields
[I want to combine/union two tables and have it create a field that identifies which table it came from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437026/i-want-to-combine-union-two-tables-and-have-it-create-a-field-that-identifies-wh)

This one has no table distinction field
[Combine two tables that have no common fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198124/combine-two-tables-that-have-no-common-fields)

Comment: How do you want them joined?  How do we determine which rows in table one should be paired with which rows in table two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `union all` operator to join the two queries and add the `idType` column by selecting a literal:

```
(SELECT `date`, `index`, idOne AS id, 'One' AS idType
 FROM   one
 WHERE  id = 5)
UNION ALL
(SELECT `date`, `index`, idTwo AS id, 'Two' AS idType
 FROM   two
 WHERE  id = 5)
```

Comment: Recommend parentheses around the queries in case OP has something complex going on in his SELECT.

Comment: @bishop good style tip, thanks. Adopted it into my answer.