# Interleave two SQL tables, group, and know which table it came from OR BOTH

Tags: mysql

As a variation on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23437026/i-want-to-combine-union-two-tables-and-have-it-create-a-field-that-identifies-wh), I want to interleave two tables, group by, and know which table the value came from *or if it came from both of them*.

For example...

```
mysql> select id, date from events order by date;
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2016-08-01 |
|  6 | 2016-08-01 |
|  4 | 2016-08-03 |
|  2 | 2016-08-05 |
|  5 | 2016-08-05 |
|  3 | 2016-08-11 |
+----+------------+

mysql> select id, date from posts order by date;
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
|  1 | 2016-08-03 |
|  2 | 2016-08-05 |
|  4 | 2016-08-05 |
|  3 | 2016-08-07 |
+----+------------+
```

I'd like this.

```
+------------+-------+
| date       | type  |
+------------+-------+
| 2016-08-01 | event |
| 2016-08-03 | both  |
| 2016-08-05 | both  |
| 2016-08-07 | post  |
| 2016-08-11 | event |
+------------+-------+
```

This is what I have, and it works. I'm wondering if it can be done better. Not just the `case`, but also the `union all`.

```
select  things.date as date,
        case bit_or(type)
        when 1 then "event"
        when 2 then "post"
        when 3 then "both"
        else "unknown"
        end as type
from (select date, 1 as type from events
               union all
      select date, 2 as type from posts
     ) things
group by things.date
order by things.date
```

Answer (score 2):

I think there is simpler logic to determine if something came from both:

```
select t.date as date,
       (case when max(which) = min(which) then max(which)
             else 'both'
        end) as type
from ((select date, 'event' as which from events
      ) union all
      (select date, 'post' as which from posts
     ) t
group by t.date
order by t.date;
```

After all, a row has to come from one table or the other.  `bit_or()` isn't necessary.

Comment: both are `both` in your case statement. I think `else which`